# Node_module needs executable

Tags: node.js, path, ffmpeg, executable

I do not understand this error I'm getting from fluent-ffmpeg: An error occurred: spawn ENOENT

I can find the exact same error on its github repo  - [same exact issue](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/278) - where they solved it by adding an executable in the required path, but where are they getting this executable and why do they need it? Also how are they adding it to the FFMPEG_PATH variable? My FFMPEG_PATH variable only contains the path to the ffmpeg node module.  Is this path not supposed to point to the node module?